# C# - Similar as string constructor but can't return result

Tags: c#, string, constructor

okay guys, i'm new in C# programming, today i was trying to create constructor which will be like a String constructor but the problem is that i have to return the result after i use it, but as i know constructora can't have return type and can't be static

```
using System;


class StringA {
  public StringA(char x, int y) {
    string res = "";
    string ConvertedChar = Convert.ToString(x);

    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
      res += ConvertedChar;
    }
    // How to return string res?
  }

}
class MainClass {
  static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine(new StringA('B', 15));
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want `new StringA('B',15)` to produce a new `StringA` instance that can be *converted* to a string in that call to `WriteLine` or do you want it to actually produce a `string` object? Because the latter seems to be what you're asking for but that's not what constructors do.

Comment: "constructors can't have return type" - I'd say that constructors do have a return type, that of the class they are constructing. They always return an instance of an object of that type (unless an exception is thrown)

Comment: @ColinMackay It may or may not work like that behind the scenes, but there's no way within the language to observe that. As far as the language is concerned, no, it doesn't have a return type. You can't specify one, and if the constructor contains a `return` statement, it must not return a value.

Comment: You are aware that this constructor already exists [String Constructor (Char, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx)? Is it only an example or are you looking for this specific case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to override the 
         ToString()
Method of your class StringA.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new StringA('B', 15));
        Console.Read();
    }
}


class StringA
{

    string res = "";

    public StringA(char x, int y)
    {
        string ConvertedChar = Convert.ToString(x);

        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            res += ConvertedChar;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return res;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a *static factory method?*

```
public static string CreateRepeatedString(char x, int y) {
   return new string(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use keyword `out` in following way:

```
class StringA
{
    public StringA(char x, int y, out string res)
    {
        res = "";
        string ConvertedChar = Convert.ToString(x);

        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            res += ConvertedChar;
        }
        // or even shorter
        // res = new string(x, y);
      }
}
```

Then you can pass some string to constrctor and get it's value changed in constructor. Then you can use it:

```
class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string res;
        Console.WriteLine(new StringA('B', 15, out res));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can create a public accessor for your class, or would you rather need a static factory method as @Joey stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48457008/7291240)?

See below example:

```
using System;

namespace YourNamespace {
  class StringA {

    private string privateVal = "";
    public string PublicVal {
      get {
        return this.privateVal;
      }
      set {
        this.privateVal = value;
      }
    }
    public StringA(char x, int y) {
      string res = "";
      string ConvertedChar = Convert.ToString(x);

      for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        res += ConvertedChar;
      }
      // How to return string res?
      this.privateVal = res; //assign res to your accessor
    }

  }
  class MainClass {
    static void Main() {
      //then you can access the public property
      Console.WriteLine(new StringA('B', 15).PublicVal);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above answers, you can also add an [implicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit)

```
class StringA
{
    private readonly string instance;
    public StringA(char x, int y)
    {
        string res = "";
        string ConvertedChar = Convert.ToString(x);

        for (int i = 0; i<y; i++)
        {
            res += ConvertedChar;
        }
        this.instance = res;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(StringA d) => d.instance;   
}
```

This can then be used as:

```
string str = new StringA('x', 10);
Console.WriteLine(new StringA('y',100));
```